# Python Script Scheduling

Tags: python

I am a complete novice, and have had a script written for me that scrapes football stats data.

I would like to automate this process nightly at 8 pm, however, have not been able to crack it.  I assume it is not overly complex - however it has been for my inexperience.

My "googling" has led me to "pip install schedule" ... and I have followed directions to create ...

```py
# au_john_finalsiren_V9.py  
import schedule 
import time

def au_john_finalsiren_V9.py()
    schedule.every().day.at(20:00:00").do(au_john_finalsiren_V9.py)

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

But I am missing something!!

All help is appreciated!!

JR

Comment: you'll have a better time using Task Scheduler or cron or whatever

Comment: Do you want to schedule your script daily ?

Comment: yes I would like to schedule daily

Comment: did look at cron but got very very confused

Comment: Happy to look at all options to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your code and function calling. Try to modify it in the following way:

```py
# au_john_finalsiren_V9.py  
import schedule 
import time

def au_john_finalsiren_V9():
    print('This is a function that is called every day at 20:00')
    

schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(au_john_finalsiren_V9)

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

In the function `au_john_finalsiren_V9` write the code that should be executed.

Comment: Hey Yury - thanks for the help.  I edited the script, and changed the time to 2 minute later than local for testing ... and it didn't run - any ideas?
Did I miss a step?

When I manually ran it - I got ...

PS G:\My Drive\1. John\FFL\FFL 2022 Administration> & C:/Users/john/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "g:/My Drive/1. John/FFL/FFL 2022 Administration/2022 Stats Files/FFL_Scraping_Schedule"
This is a function that is called every day at 20:00

But the py script didn't run...

Comment: Yes, there were a double quotes missing. I've fixed the script now.

Comment: Thanks I have updated and saved... and changed the time setting to "14:40" to test 

The script still didn't run though.. the au_john_finalsiren_V9.py script is existing and is sitting in the same folder as the code I have copied from your post

Comment: You cannot run in this way another script from the same folder. Check if my code works with simple print statement. If it works than the issue is in how you call external script.